# Custom Domain Mapping in CakePHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

I am coding on a social site in CakePHP say `example.com`, here in the users profiles are located at `example.com/profiles/user1`. Now I need to provide the functionality to the users to use their custom domains for profiles. For example `user1.com` should render content from `example.com/profiles/user1`

Please suggest me the best solution for my problem. I am working on Shared Hosting - Linux Server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you both have a wildcard record in DNS and that the webserver is configured to serve your Cake project from those hostnames (*how* to do these things will depend upon your hosting provider), then (with thanks to [Subdomaining with Cake](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Mum_Chamber/2008/02/04/subdomaining-with-cake)), you simply need to place the following in `app/config/bootstrap.php`:

```
$subdomain = substr( env('HTTP_HOST'), 0, strpos(env('HTTP_HOST'), '.') ); 
if( strlen($subdomain)>0 && $subdomain != 'www' ) { 
    $_GET['url'] = 'user/' . $subdomain . '/' . (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '');
}
```

Comment: Didn't get that! Can you elaborate the steps.

Comment: I am confused, what the sub domain need to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality, you need to point user1.com to example.com/profiles/user1

For this I can think of two methods:

**1. Name server Method:**

you can change name servers of user1.com to your example.com name servers like:

*ns1.example.com*

*ns2.example.com*

NOTE: This may take 3-4 hours to work

**2. URL Forwarding Method:**

You can also use URL forwarding to point user1.com to example.com .
This will give you basic idea of forwarding http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name

Comment: -1 Simply changing the nameservers of one domain to those of another will result in *lame delegation*, which will break that domain entirely: the nameservers to which delegation has been changed must first have been configured to serve that zone (and in any event, delegation has absolutely nothing at all to do with this question).